# read one char at a time until i reach an empty space in C#

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I'm really lost here, don't know what i did wrong.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (@"Destination.txt");
int i=0;
char[] word = new char[16];
While (reader.Peek().ToString() != " ")
{
    word[i] = (char)reader.Read(); //This is when the debugger stops, after 16 iterations.
    i++;
}
```

I know that for sure, that in the txt, there is always a space after a maximum of 15 characters so it shouldn't exceed the word array boundary, but it does. What am i doing wrong here?
The reason i used Tostring is because it the Peek command kept returning an Int for some reason.

Comment: Not sure, but try to compare to `' '` as a char, instead of a string?

Comment: Well what do you know!? it worked! i did (char) instead of tostring and compared to ' ' and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Peek` returns the code of the char, not the char itself, so you need to convert it:

```
while ((char)reader.Peek() != ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks! Marcin told me to do that in the comments and it works, thanks for the help how silly of me.

Comment: @Bodokh, it's a good idea to understand to root cause here. Which was not about just comparing to wrong literal (after all, in the code above you can call `ToString()` for the left side). It was about misinterpreting the `Peek` function result.

Answer (score 0):

When StreamReader.Peek() return -1 , that mean end of file.

```
while (reader.Peek() != -1)
```